how can i know if a sequence/ set of random variables of are independent
am working on understanding the relationship between the distribution of random variables and their independence. Specifically, if I have random variables

1
,

2
,
…
,


X
1
​
,X
2
​
,…,X
n
​
, each distributed as
Bernoulli
(

)
Bernoulli(p) or
Binomial
(

,

)
Binomial(n,p), does this necessarily mean that the variables

1
,

2
,
…
,


X
1
​
,X
2
​
,…,X
n
​
are independent?
If not, what conditions are sufficient to establish that

1
,

2
,
…
,


X
1
​
,X
2
​
,…,X
n
​
are independent?
I understand that a common misconception is to assume that identical distributions imply independence. However, I know this is not true in general. For instance, variables can be identically distributed but still dependent if they share some underlying structure

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

See definition 3.2 here.

Also, for your first question, let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be identically distributed, if $X_1=X_2$, are they independent?
